# mysql union with NULL fields

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Does the mysql `UNION` and `UNION ALL` operator always remove rows that have a NULL in them?

I am doing a `UNION` of two SELECT statements - one of which may return a row with a NULL in it. When it does, it does not include that row in the UNION. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNION/UNION ALL does not remove rows with NULL in them.

`UNION` removes duplicate rows; `UNION ALL` does not, and is faster than `UNION` for it.

Check your data & your query for why NULLs you expect to see are not visible.

Comment: This is strange, it seems to work now. All I really did was change the primary key to a unique index and set the field in the table to allow NULL (which was part of the primary key). But it still didn't work after that. Then it suddenly did, and it still does after setting it back.