# SQL union all not includes zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server, zero, union-all

I am using union all to unite several queries, but union all is not inserting an empty row for those zero values. I took a look in the site and according to this question, it should include them:

[mysql union with NULL fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440311/mysql-union-with-null-fields)

These are my queries:

```
select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 1 and SMTH > 0 )  
union all
select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 2 and SMTH > 0 )  
union all
select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 3 and SMTH > 0 )  
union all
select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 4 and SMTH > 0 )
```

Result:

```
10068
3967
895
```

Four independent queries:

```
select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 1 and SMTH > 0 )  

select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 2 and SMTH > 0 )  

select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 3 and SMTH > 0 )  

select [SMTH] from [H].[D].[T]
where Date = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from [H].[D].[T] where Data = 4 and SMTH > 0 )
```

Result:

```
10068
3967
0
895
```

So basically since I think that the answer from the previous question is right, what am I doing wrong?.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this is mysql? The use of `[]` for identifiers is typical of Sql Server.

Comment: This is SQL, but the question answered previously was for MySQL

Comment: 1. Are `Date` values unique within the table? 2. How/where exactly did you obtain the results for your four independent queries? Could it be that the third query actually produced no rows and the application that returned you the result just defaulted to displaying `0`?

Comment: The Dates will be always unique, and the query is working properly is returning a 0 which is the correct data stored in the table.

Comment: If Dates are unique, then how could the third query return `0`? The subquery's condition is "Data = 3 and **SMTH > 0**", i.e. the MAX(Date) found (if indeed found) by the subquery should belong to a row where `SMTH` is greater than 0. And your main query *is* pulling the very SMTH, so there just can't be any `0` in the output. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Which column is null?
Are you sure, the nulls aren't removed due to your where clause?
Remember that operations with null always result in null (except testing with IS NULL).

Comment: I changed the column, stupidly I mistaken zero by null where I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The third query returns 0. Why do you think that is null? Any way this query is cleaner than the `union`:

If the table has a primary key (id in this query):

```
select SMTH, Data, [date]
from 
    H.D.T
    inner join (
        select id, Data, max([date]) as [date]
        from H.D.T
        where Data in (1, 2, 3, 4) and SMTH > 0
        group by id, Data
    ) s on s.id = H.D.T.id
order by Data
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake for expressing a 0 value with the word null. I fixed the question. "I am using union all to unite several queries, but union all is not inserting an empty row for those zero values"

Comment: That query dont work: Column "H.D.T.data" is invalid in the ORDER BY H.D.T.SMTH clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Hi Clodoaldo thanks for your answer, that query still doesn't do what I want. I want from the H.D.T to return for each Data value (1, 2, 3 and 4) the value of SMTH for the maximum Date

Comment: Hi Clodoaldo thanks again, I think there is a problem with the new table s, if i run it it says. No column name was specified for column 3 of 's'. I ahve tried to fix it by myself but I couldn't figure out. Thanks a lot seriously!.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16925/discussion-between-eduardo-and-clodoaldo)